# SWIG typemap uint8_t* from C/C++ to java.nio.ByteBuffer

Tags: java, c++, swig

I'm trying to pass an input and an output buffer to a java class from C++.
For efficiency reasons, I need to use a ByteBuffer.

Both of the buffers were allocated in the C++ part and I need to pass them to a java function that will use the input buffer for some computation and write the result into the output buffer.

Here is an simplified example of how the C++ looks like:

```
// SWIG mapped with %feature("director") JavaDelegate;
class JavaDelegate {
public:
    JavaDelegate() {}
    virtual ~JavaDelegate() {}
    virtual int compute(const uint8_t* input, size_t inSize,
                        uint8_t* output, size_t maxOutSize,
                        int someFlag) = 0;
};

// assume inputBuf is filled with valid data
std::vector<uint8_t> inputBuf;
std::vector<uint8_t> outputBuf(10000);

// delegate also points to a valid SWIG mapped class
JavaDelegate* delegate;

void computeOutput() {
   int someFlag = 1;
   int numValuesComputed = delegate->compute(inputBuf.data(), inputBuf.size(), 
                                             outputBuf.data(), outputBuf.size(), 
                                             someFlag);
   std::cout << "Computed " << numValuesComputed << " value from input.\n";
}
```

On the Java side, I want to achieve this (`JavaDelegate` class has been generated by SWIG):

```
public class Delegate extends JavaDelegate {

    public long compute(java.nio.ByteBuffer input, 
                        java.nio.ByteBuffer output, 
                        long someFlag) 
    {
        // read input
        // compute something n values from m input values
        // write result to output
        return numOutputValues;
    }
}
```

The problem is, I simply can't figure out how to do the typemaps to wrap a plain char* to a ByteBuffer, especially in conjunction with SWIG's director feature turned on for the abstract baseclass.
I know how to pass a ByteBuffer from Java to C++ but I can't find out how to do the reverse.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: I would pass a DirectByteBuffer from Java to C++ for it to populate, you can avoid copying the data by altering the address and capacity.

Comment: The output buffer is actually a hardware buffer, so I can't really allocate it from java. Of course I could copy it back to the hardware buffer afterwards, but I'd prefer to simply map it directly to java if possible.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15414753/shared-memory-between-c-and-java-processes

Comment: appreciate your help, but this is about creating a SWIG typemap for it. E.g. The way from Java to C++ has been done in https://github.com/swig/swig/blob/master/Lib/java/various.i But the reverse is missing.

Answer (score 1):

Preface: this is not SWIG-ish solution, this is general purpose, I found [this](https://qinjin.wordpress.com/2011/10/11/mapping-between-char-and-byte-in-swig/) somewhat related to your question

---

First, there are no `ref` parameters in Java as far as I know so passing it directly from C++ is not an option unless you are ready to change your signature and have it as a return value. This would be possible to circumvent by passing typewrapper from Java and having C++ creating/setting buffer inside it, a la:

```
public class BufferWrapper {
    private ByteBuffer mBuffer;

    public void setBuffer(ByteBuffer buffer) {
        mBuffer = buffer;
    }
}
```

Just pass this to C++ and have it allocate and set buffer to wrapper.

There's [NewDirectByteBuffer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#NewDirectByteBuffer) JNI function that does exactly what you need:

> Allocates and returns a direct java.nio.ByteBuffer referring to the
>   block of memory starting at the memory address address and extending
>   capacity bytes.
>
> Native code that calls this function and returns the resulting
>   byte-buffer object to Java-level code should ensure that the buffer
>   refers to a valid region of memory that is accessible for reading and,
>   if appropriate, writing. An attempt to access an invalid memory
>   location from Java code will either return an arbitrary value, have no
>   visible effect, or cause an unspecified exception to be thrown.

---

P.S we could have gone other way - ByteBuffer has [wrap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#wrap(byte[])) method that would allow you to wrap existing buffer of `byte[]` which is not exactly `char*` but we could marry them (look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17124712/jni-android-converting-char-to-byte-array-and-return-it-to-java())).

In depth of your Jni method implmentation:

```
 jsize n = sizeof(yourBuf);
 jbyteArray arr = (*env)->NewByteArray(env, n);
 (*env)->SetByteArrayRegion(env,arr,0,n, (jbyte*)yourBuf);
```

**However** note that according to [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html) this function incurs **copy** not just wrapping so I doom it not very helpful here

Comment: I think your answer is spot on. I found this https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/qpid/branches/address-refactor2/qpid/cpp/bindings/swig_java_typemaps.i which does something pretty similar to what you describe. I'm fine with changing my signatures as well. Right now, I'm trying to pass a wrapper that keeps track of the pointer to the data. This seems to be the way to go here. I'l post the complete code once i get it working. Thanks Oleg!

Comment: I need to do the same thing - do you still have that code?

Answer (score 0):

One way to go about is to extend the C++ class to return a ByteBuffer. Roughly speaking, one could go about it like this:

```
%extend some::namespace::Buffer {
    jobject byteBuffer() {
        if (cached_jvm != 0) {
            JNIEnv *env = JNU_GetEnv();
            return env->NewDirectByteBuffer($self->get(), $self->size());
        }
    }
}
```

Additionally, you will need this code somewhere in your swig.i file to cache the jenv on startup.

```
%{
#include <stdexcept>
#include "jni.h"

static JavaVM *cached_jvm = 0;

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL JNI_OnLoad(JavaVM *jvm, void *reserved) {
  cached_jvm = jvm;
  return JNI_VERSION_1_2;
}

static JNIEnv * JNU_GetEnv() {
  JNIEnv *env;
  jint rc = cached_jvm->GetEnv((void **)&env, JNI_VERSION_1_2);
  if (rc == JNI_EDETACHED)
    throw std::runtime_error("current thread not attached");
  if (rc == JNI_EVERSION)
    throw std::runtime_error("jni version not supported");
  return env;
}
%}
```

You might be able to get away without enabling the director feature support.

Now you can call the extended function in Java somewhat like this:

```
ByteBuffer bb = (ByteBuffer)nativeBufferReference.byteBuffer();
```