# Create std::function accepting std::vector (mapped to ByteBuffer) between c++ and java with SWIG

Tags: java, c++, swig

I've tried to cobble together code from:
[SWIG typemap uint8_t* from C/C++ to java.nio.ByteBuffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41301653/swig-typemap-uint8-t-from-c-c-to-java-nio-bytebuffer/41305617#41305617)

To pass java.nio.ByteBuffer from java to std::array& for the C++ calls.

I'd like to do something similar with then answer from https://stackoverflow.com/users/168175/flexo in
[How to use SWIG to wrap std::function objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32644268/how-to-use-swig-to-wrap-stdfunction-objects) for std::function (but I'm ok with the simple answer).

In particular I'd like a Java callback class that I can implement java for

```
std::function<void(const std::vector<uint8_t> &)>
```

to the C++ side,

```
uint32_t registerForEvent(const std::vector<uint8_t> &event, std::function<void(const std::vector<uint8_t> &)> process)
```

and have the c++ side call that function and have the java side be able to override/implement the call:

```
public class myCallback extends Callback {
   public void call(java.nio.ByteBuffer data) {
      /* do something with data */
   }
}
```

I think I need some use of env->NewDirectByteBuffer(ptr,size) from something like
[SWIG typemap uint8_t* from C/C++ to java.nio.ByteBuffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41301653/swig-typemap-uint8-t-from-c-c-to-java-nio-bytebuffer)
initialized from the std::vector& sent from C++ to happen with the param/unpack/lvalref/forward.

Is there some sneaky way to make that happen with the generalized VA_ARGS macros?
Or even just the oneshot for my simple case of the specific std::function: